# How does Server 2012 know?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How does the server recognize a WebAPI call from a "regular" URL?  I have written a WebAPI project that works quite nicely when run via Visual Studio 2013 but does not run when published to our development server 2012 or to my newly installed local server 2012.  Note that the second server is not the VS "local" server.  Is there a plug in that I need to install on the servers to "teach" them about WebAPI? Both servers ruturn 404 errors (file not found).
URL running on local server 2012: http://localhost/DataAccess/api/VoicePortal/GetDNIS_DATA/2064082473

Comment: There is no difference between a request to a Web Site URL and a request to a Web API URL.  Most likely it is a configuration issue with your IIS web host on the server.

Comment: Did you configure your firewall, ports, etc etc to actually handle the request on that server?